# Система хранения контента, многослойная архитектура

Tags: ооп, mongodb, проектирование

Мне нужно написать систему управления контентом (большими файлами). Я хочу использовать в этой системе четырехслойную архитектуру (слой бизнеса, слов сценариев, интерфейсов и инфраструктуры). Файлы могут быть временными и сохраненными в MongoDB GridFS. Ко временным файлам можно аппендить байты, кроме того, временные файлы можно коммитить в GridFS. Бизнес-логика такова, что нельзя закоммитить файл, если его чексумма некорректна (предполагаемая чексумма поступает в HTTP-заголовке).

Как реализовать абстракцию файла в этой системе? Предполагается, что файлы будут управляться репозиториями (паттерном). Может быть, конечно, есть вариант лучше. Как это сделать?

Логика приблизительно такова: есть три запроса, запрос создания временного файла, запрос дописывания байтов в его конец и запрос коммита в базу. У файла нужно проверять его чексумму. Файл можно доставать из БД и передавать по HTTP. Как сделать это в ООП?

К какому слою относится абстракция файла и к какому - репозитории?

У меня неплохая архитектура на уровне domain и usecases, но ниже творится безобразие из-за того, что я не написал абстракцию файла и не могу работать с файлами как с одной сущностью, независимо от того, на диске они или в базе.